how to invoke a job from another job within the same github workflow run
I have a workflow with 2 jobs in the strategy matrix like the one below.
Both jobs have protection rules for Environment prompting for Manual approval.
Upon Approving and executing the first job, I wish to pass the job-name of the other & get the triggered automatically.
name: NEW Loop Over Comma-Separated Values

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  createloopmatrix:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    outputs: 
      MATRIX: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.MATRIX }}
      ENV-VARS: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.ENV-VARS }}

    steps:
      - name: Run PowerShell 
        id: set-matrix
        shell: pwsh
        run: |

          $EnvNamesJSONVariable = @{}
          $envList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
          $displayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
          
          $color = "hello, yellow"
          $values = $color.Split(',')

          $matrix = @()
          $envVars = @{}

          foreach ($value in $values) {
            $matrixName = "MA_$value"
            $matrix += @{ "DISPLAYLIST" = $matrixName; "CUSTOMENVNAME" = $value }
            $envVars."$value" = $value
            Write-Output "Value: $value"
          }

          echo "MATRIX=$($matrix | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100)" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          echo "ENV-VARS=$($envVars | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100)" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          

  Trigger_Service:
    name: ${{ matrix.DISPLAYLIST }}
    needs: 
      - ${{ matrix.DEPENDENTNAME }}
    #needs: [createloopmatrix]
    runs-on: windows-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include: ${{ fromJson(needs.createloopmatrix.outputs.MATRIX) }}
    environment:
      name: ${{ matrix.CUSTOMENVNAME }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Split Matrix name for use
        run: |
          Write-Host "Inside Matrix"

Snapshot of the run:

As you can see if I manually approve MA_hello the solution I'm expecting here should run and trigger MA_yellow job with the same user without the need for manual approval.
Kindly suggest.

For what I understand, you want both approvals to happen in sequence, and not in parallel. To do so, you could use the max-parallel input, setting it to 1. Now, I don't get why you're configuring 2 approvals if the second one is passed automatically when the first one is approved.

@GuiFalourd the requirement is different and has nothing to do with max-parallel.  Approving and running the first job manually should trigger the run for the second job bypassing manual approval for Environment of the second job.

You may not want to use matrix in that case, as the idea of matrix is to reuse configurations for similar behaviors. Here, you want the behavior of the first manual approval to be different from the second one. Is there another reason why you need to use a matrix strategy here? Otherwise in that case, using 3 jobs, when the second depends on the first one, and the third depends on the second, could attend your expectations.

The matrix values are picked from a database in ORDER. It starts off like this ... Approval_Dev -> Devhost1 -> Devhost2 -> Devhost3 -> Approval_QA -> QAhost1 -> QAhost2
I wish if the Team lead approves (using Environment protection rules) Approval_Dev then all subsequent jobs viz Devhost1, Devhost2, Devhost3 should be auto-approved and run despite protection rules and then wait on second manual approval i.e. Approval_QA. Hope I make sense for the requirement @GuiFalourd.

It make sense, but you won't be able to achieve this using 1 job with matrix strategy alone, you will need many jobs with dependency (needs) between them. You'll need your job1 (setup job to get the values from the database and set outputs), then job2 (approval_dev) which needs job1, then job3 (matrix strategy using output from job1 with DevHost1,2,3) which needs job1 and job2, then job4 (approval_qa) which needs job3, then job5 (matrix strategy using output from job1 with QAhost1,2,3) which needs job1 and job4. Does it make sense? I can add an answer with a yaml if needed

@GuiFalourd i tried your suggestion but looks like needs does not support variable like how runs-on does
    needs:       - set-global-runner       - ${{ matrix.agent.dependname }}
Gets me syntax error Invalid values: ${{ matrix.agent.dependname }}

I believe the needs field doesn't support interpolation, you need to inform specific job name. If your job names may change due to the environment, I would suggest doing all this orchestration in a reusable workflow, that would behave the same for all environments, and use the reusable workflow inputs to select the env.

My usecase everytime would be Approval_Dev -> Devhost1 -> Devhost2 -> Devhost3 -> Approval_QA -> QAhost1 -> QAhost2 -> Approval_UAT -> UAThost1 -> UAThost2 -> UAThost3
As we understood needs: does not support interpolation, i m unsure and have not understood if my requirement is achievable using reusable workflow or otherwise? Could you help with sample workflow having any example of sorts?

My suggestion is for you to use a reusable workflow for each group of 3 host jobs: Devhost1 -> Devhost2 -> Devhost3 + QAhost1 -> QAhost2 -> QAhost3 + UAThost1 -> UAThost2 -> UAThost3 as the configurations are probably the same for all those groups, with just a difference in the env variables. That way you would have Approval_Dev -> Reusable (input DEV) -> Approval_QA -> Reusable (input QA) -> Approval_UAT -> Reusable (input UAT). Each reusable job config would just depend on the previous approval job.

@GuiFalourd, can you show how the caller and reusable will look like with environment? I understand reusable having environment would also require approval, if protection rule is in place.

In that case, the environment name could be used as input to the reusable workflow according to the trigger. Wouldn´t it?
